# RobotFramework: Finding Xpath containing text

Tags: xpath, selector, robotframework

So my link at the below location contains the words 'Download certificate'

```
xpath=//*[@id="training_list_table"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/span/a/text()
```

I want to be more specific in my search so that it doesn't just accept any old text so something like...

```
xpath=//*[@id="training_list_table"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/span/a/text()='Download certificate'
```

But this lets me down. What is the correct syntax to do such a search?

Comment: You should check the `href` attribute and see if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match link that

- *contains text* `"Download certificate"` you might use

  ```
  //a[contains(., "Download certificate")]
  ```
- *starts with text* `"Download certificate"`:

  ```
  //a[starts-with(., "Download certificate")]
  ```
- has *exact text* `"Download certificate"`:

  ```
  //a[.="Download certificate"]
  ```

If there are more than one link that contains `"Download certificate"` in a table you might specify appropriate ancestor by specific attribute, text or index, e.g. `//td[5]//a[.="Download certificate"]`- you don't have to include group of ancestors in your `XPath` like `.../tbody/tr/td[5]/span/...`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could try something like this:

```
xpath=//*[@id="training_list_table"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/span/a[contains(text(), 'Download certificate')]
```

//*[contains(text(), '')] is the key..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

```
xpath=//*[@id="training_list_table"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/span/a[@text='Download certificate']
```